# TYPO3 - custom caching for logged users

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Scenario:
There are three types of visitors on my TYPO3 website:

1. not logged in visitor
2. logged in user - without 'full access'
3. logged in user - with 'full access'

'full access' - at the moment it is some specific relation from fe_users that decides about that. If that help somehow - I can differentiate it by assigning some special usergroup additionally.

limited content - There is some special set of pages on my website - for visitors 1 and 2 no main tt_content column is displayed at all on those set of pages - instead some text about membership is displayed. I can do that easily with viewhelper which is checking privileges. So far everything good - functionality works fine if cache is disabled for that pages.

The problem is when caching is enabled:

- when user 1 or 2 opens the page first then the page is cached without content and when user 3 opens the page later - will see it the same way.
- vice versa - when user 3 opens the page first it will be cached with all the content and visitors 1 and 2 will see it the same way

I want all cases to be taken from the cache. So I am wondering if it is possible to store different versions of same page (with same url)? Example depending on some user related logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate these cases in the cache storing.

That can be done be TYPO3 itself if you insert conditions in your typoscript.
For each condition in typoscript a new cache section is used. So with each condition you technically double the amount of cache. (in reality it is less, as not each combination of condition results in a visible page).

As you suggested individual fe_user-groups would be fine to build easier conditions. AFAIK the conditions could be empty (evaluation is done in plugins).

```
[usergroup = 1]
[usergroup = 2]
[else]
[global]
```